# How to share connection through wireless router in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I found some informations but all confusing.
I have an ubuntu box 12.04 connected to internet via cable with a fixed ip inside a wide internal network. The cable is plugged into motherboard network interface, that is configured with his ip, dns and so on.
I bought an extra network interface card and plugged a apple airport extreme router to the second interface. I want the router to share connection with other devices using the connection taken by the cable.
How i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the network layout is as follows,

clients <-wireless-> airport <-eth1-> ubuntu <-eth0-> ISP

With this setup you will need to have ip forwarding enabled and have iptables setup correctly to masquerade all the traffic from eth1 to eth0.

Eg:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

All you need to do is then to persist these changes.

Comment: I solved using an ubuntu setting (in graphical enviroment) Settings -> Network Connections -> Wired -> eth1 -> Edit -> IPv4 Settings -> Method -> 'Shared to other computer' and set the airport in dhcp. I guess it is the same thing but, in your case, using terminal, isn't? Thank you very much for the answer!